# Error Installing PostgreSQL - Copying compressed file NodeIndexOnlyScan.sh

Tags: windows, postgresql, postgresql-12, postgresql-13

When I try to install postgresql I receive this error message:

[image]

I thought there was an error with installer, so I tried a PostgreSQL 12 installer, but same error in a different location:

[image]

Even, I downloaded a new installer but nothing seems to work. Every time, it was executed as administrator.

When I press skip, the process ends without incidents. I'm running Windows 10 Pro, version 2004, comp 19041.572

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with Kaspersky, the antivirus was blocking the file copy. So excluding the folder or disabling Kaspersky can fix the problem!